# Intro to Stats Question

Tags: statistics, economics

Life tests performed on a sample of 100 batteries indicated: (1) an average life of 75 months, (2) a standard deviation of 5 months, and (3) a bell shaped battery life distribution. What percentage of the batteries will fail within the first 65 months of use? The answer is 2.5% just wondering how to get there?

Comment: If we let $X$ be the lifespan of a single battery, we can treat $X$ as a continuous random variable. Then what distribution does $X$ have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 'normal' (bell-shaped) distribution, about 95% of all batteries' lifespan lie within two standard deviations of the mean. In other words, about 95% have a life span between $75-2*5=65$ and $75+2*5=85$ months. And that means that about 5% have a lifespan that lies outside that interval, with about half of that (i.e 2.5%) below 65 months and the other half (i.e 2.5%) over 85 months. These are all rough approximations though.

Comment: So you find 95% lies on the left side of 65%. Then divide the 5% by 2 since we're only looking on the left side to get 2.5%?

Comment: @AlexVincent roughly 95% lies between 65 and 85, and so 5% is outside of that interval, with roughly half of that 5% below 65 and the other half of that 5% above 85